# twitter error 401 - What should I do with the exclamation mark?

Tags: objective-c, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have a problem with Oauth and twitter api ver1.1. My app will tweet a post to twitter when post something to another site. But when the post body contains exclamation mark ('!'), I get twitter 401 error that is 'Unauthorized'. I searched on google, and found that it may related to Oauth. Some people says that the '!' must be encoded to '%21'. I tried it, but when I tweet '!' to twitter, I just got '%21' but not '!' itself. How can I encode the '!' correctly?

Comment: As an addition info, I'm using MGTwitterEngine.

Comment: try encode "!" to &#33;

Comment: Hi @torip3ng, thanks for the answer but this time I got '&#33', still not '!'.

Comment: Have you fixed it yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must encode your tweet with this category

```
#import "NSString+URLEncoding.h"
@implementation NSString (OAURLEncodingAdditions)

- (NSString *)URLEncodedString 
{
    NSString *result = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                       (CFStringRef)self,
                                                                       NULL,
                                                                       CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"),
                                                                       kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    [result autorelease];
    return result;
}

- (NSString*)URLDecodedString
{
    NSString *result = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                                       (CFStringRef)self,
                                                                                       CFSTR(""),
                                                                                       kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    [result autorelease];
    return result;  
}

@end
```

Comment: Hi, @myke. Thank you for the answer. I found the URLEncodedString: method in the class 'OAMutableURLRequest' while did not find the URLDecodedString: in my project. The URLEncodedString: is used by some other methods. Can you tell me where should I use the URLDecodedString: ?

Comment: I don't know ;) In my Twitter client I don't use this method

Comment: @Sabbath, How did you solve this? It would be good if you can put a separate answer for the same. :)

Comment: @Hemang, I solved this just by adding '!' to CFSTR("") in the implementation of URLEncodedString.