# Post message to twitter with exclamation mark

Tags: objective-c, twitter, twitter-oauth

It seems my iOS app cant post to Twitter if that post contatins a "!". My return error code is 401. However I can post messages that don't contain the exclamation mark. I tried encoding the ! to %21 but that just post the message of Twitter with the %21 in the body.

How can I post a message to Twitter that contains a "!"?

Answer (score 0):

Encode your `NSString`:

```
encodedTweet = [tweet stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Another solution is described in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399066/twitter-error-401what-should-i-do-with-the-exclamation-mark).

Comment: that doesn't replace the exclamation mark with anything and still gives me the 401 error when posting a message with a "!"

Comment: It's a known issue with v1.1 api. Check this: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/12378 they also describe solutions there

Comment: Edited my answer too.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I tried that already but that answer post my message with the encoded symbols and not the !

Comment: That is not correct, post some code where you make the request in order to help you.